# Flutter: Implementing Video Playback on Mouse Hover Without Memory Leaks

Tags: flutter, video

```
class ToolsWorksItemView extends StatefulWidget {
  final WorksData model;
  const ToolsWorksItemView({Key? key, required this.model}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToolsWorksItemView> createState() => _ToolsWorksItemViewState();
}

class _ToolsWorksItemViewState extends State<ToolsWorksItemView> {
  MainTopController mainTop = Get.find();
  VideoPlayerController? _controller;
  CustomVideoPlayerController? _customVideoPlayerController;
  bool showText = false;

  void _initializeVideoPlayer() {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(
        "${ApiConfig.baseUrl}/app/gateway/download/file_object_data/${widget.model.fileObjectId}?token=${mainTop.userToken}"))
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
        //_controller!.play();
      });
    _controller?.setLooping(true);
    _customVideoPlayerController = CustomVideoPlayerController(
        context: context,
        videoPlayerController: _controller!,
        customVideoPlayerSettings: const CustomVideoPlayerSettings(
          playbackSpeedButtonAvailable: false,
          settingsButtonAvailable: false,
          showDurationPlayed: false,
          controlBarAvailable: false,
          playOnlyOnce: false,
          showFullscreenButton: false,
        ));
  }

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(
  //       "${ApiConfig.baseUrl}/app/gateway/download/file_object_data/${widget.model.fileObjectId}?token=${mainTop.userToken}"))
  //     ..initialize().then((value) => setState(() {}));
  //   _controller?.setLooping(true);
  //   _customVideoPlayerController = CustomVideoPlayerController(
  //       context: context,
  //       videoPlayerController: _controller!,
  //       customVideoPlayerSettings: const CustomVideoPlayerSettings(
  //         playbackSpeedButtonAvailable: false,
  //         settingsButtonAvailable: false,
  //         showDurationPlayed: false,
  //         controlBarAvailable: false,
  //         playOnlyOnce: false,
  //         showFullscreenButton: false,
  //       ));
  // }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        double width = constraints.maxWidth;
        return InkWell(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              _controller == null || _controller!.value.isInitialized
                  ? ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      child: Image.network(
                        "${ApiConfig.baseUrl}/app/gateway/download/file_object_data_thumbnail-large/${widget.model.fileObjectId}?token=${mainTop.userToken}",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ))
                  : ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      child: CustomVideoPlayer(
                          customVideoPlayerController:
                              _customVideoPlayerController!),
                    ),
              showText
                  ? Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                      width: width,
                      height: width / _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text("title"),
                          //const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                          Text(Get.locale!.languageCode == "zh"
                              ? widget.model.name ?? ""
                              : widget.model.ename ?? ""),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : const SizedBox.shrink(),
            ],
         

        ),
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint(
                "${ApiConfig.baseUrl}/app/gateway/download/file_object_data/${widget.model.fileObjectId}?token=${mainTop.userToken}");
          },
          onHover: (isHovering) {
            if (isHovering) {
              if (_controller == null) {
                _initializeVideoPlayer();
              }
              setState(() {
                showText = true;
              });
              _controller!.play();
            } else {
              setState(() {
                showText = false;
              });
              _controller?.pause();
              _controller?.dispose();
              _controller = null;
              _customVideoPlayerController = null;
            }
          },
          // onHover: (isHovering) {
          //   if (isHovering) {
          //     setState(() {
          //       showText = true;
          //     });
          //     _controller.play();
          //   } else {
          //     setState(() {
          //       showText = false;
          //     });
          //     _controller.pause();
          //   }
          // },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I'm a Flutter novice, and I'm trying to implement a feature where a video plays when the mouse hovers over an image and stops when the mouse leaves. Initially, I created the player in initState (as indicated by the commented part), which achieved the desired functionality but led to memory leaks. So, I thought of creating a player only when the mouse hovers over the image and then releasing the memory once the mouse leaves. I'm not sure if this approach is reasonable. Currently, the issue with my code is that when the mouse hovers over the image, the screen flickers briefly as if the layout changes, and the player's appearance seems to be inconsistent with the original image's position, causing isHover to rapidly toggle between true and false. As a result, the video does not play as expected.

Comment: Most likely the problem is the constant recreation of a new video player object each time you hover. Create a single player then use the [Visibility class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) to make it hidden/visible as needed. See [this tutorial for example](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-show-and-hide-widgets-in-flutter). You might need also to set a boolean (true/false) for the parameter **maintainInteractivity**.

Comment: Sorry I meant create one player and use play/pause on hover in/out. Not sure where the 
 Visibility part came from (it's possible I read two questions before answering this one). If there is a memory leak from just pausing a file then show some testable code for that result and also a testable video file link. I suggest **(1)** Use your original code. **(2)** Try using `if (isHovering == true )` just to be sure the compiler is doing what you want. **(3)** Use `Visibility` on the text. **(4)** Memory leak is from constant re-creation of multiple copies of same thing, so find that in your code.